# Ionic - App works fine on browser and iOS simulator but not in android simulator

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am really new to the mobile development world and trying my hands on it using IonicFramework.

I am creating a login form and on successful login the user gets take to another state which is called `viewMyList`. Everything seems to be working fine when I run the command `ionic serve` I am able to login and proceed to the next state and all seems to be fine on iOS simulator as well but on Android simulator on clicking the login button nothing happens, I don't see any error either.

**My attempt**

`login.html`

```
<ion-view title="Login">
    <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
        <form class="list">
            <h2 id="login-heading3" style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">Welcome back!</h2>
            <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 32px;"></div>
            <ion-list>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="credentials.username">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="credentials.password">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 18px;"></div>
            <a class="button button-positive  button-block" ng-click="login()">Sign In</a>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

`ng-click` is linked with `login()`

Here is my `loginCtrl` which contains the `login()` function

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicHistory, User) {

    $scope.credentials = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };
    $scope.login = function () {
        User.login($scope.credentials)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                //Login should not keep any history
                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({historyRoot: true});
                $state.go('app.viewMyList');
            })
    };

    $scope.message = "this is a message loginCtrl";
})
```

Here is my `User` service that takes care of the login logic

```
angular.module('app.user', [])
    .factory('User', function ($http) {

        var apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
        var loggedIn = false;

        return {
        login: function (credentials) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify('inside login function'));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(credentials));
            return $http.post(apiUrl + '/tokens', credentials)
                .success(function (response) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify('inside .then of login function'));
                    var token = response.data.token;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(token));
                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
                    persist(token);
                })

                .error(function (response) {
                    console.log('inside error of login function');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                })
                ;
        },

            isLoggedIn: function () {
                if (localStorage.getItem("token")  != null) {
                    return loggedIn = true;
                }
            }
        };

        function persist(token) {

            window.localStorage['token'] = angular.toJson(token);
        }
    });
```

Here is the `route` behind the login

```
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'


    })
```

I am really clueless at the moment as I cant seem to figure out why nothing happens on Android, from my troubleshooting all I could find was when I click on login button the code does not seem to be going inside the following function.

```
$scope.login = function () {
    User.login($scope.credentials)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            //Login should not keep any history
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({historyRoot: true});
            $state.go('app.viewMyList');
        })
};
```

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: check console on chrome remote debugger

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? I am not having the issue on browser it is the android simulator I am having issue with.

Comment: yeah that's why i am telling you check console while you are running on your android device.
connect your android device to your laptop open chrome type `chrome://inspect` then you can inspect you app running on your device.

Comment: I see now what you are saying, i am running the simulator `ionic run android -l -c -s` command so all the logs i can see on the terminal and in that i see no error

Comment: I updated the code and added `.error` inside `login: function (credentials) {` and i can now see that only on android the flow goes into this function but still i dont see any error, `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` inside `.error` just prints out `null`

Comment: do you have `cordova-plugin-whitelist` installed?

Comment: no I did not install this, I will read about it and see how this can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install whitelist plugin first.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

add following code in your **config.xml** file under your root directory of project

```
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />
```

or:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

If still you are facing any issue, then you can check console while you are running in android device using [chrome remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)

- Connect your device with your machine.(Make sure USB debugging should be enable on your mobile).
- write `chrome://inspect` in browser in your desktop chrome.
- you will see connected device, select inspect and check console for log.

Comment: `Plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on android.` is what i see in console when i try to `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` and the `allow-navigation` does not help either

Comment: i asked you before you have whitelist installed you say no

Comment: sorry, I am really new to the mobile development world so I did not know what all cordova plugin come pre installed with ionic

Comment: did't you check your chrome console of your android device yet?

Comment: sorry for the late response, yes i did check and the error i get is `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` this does not make any sense why i am getting this error?

Comment: make sure you api is enable for CORS ( Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ).

Comment: Your comment on checking chrome console for android helped trouble shoot it. If you want to change your answer to how to use chrome console to debug android, I will then accept it. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.